# Improve query time of Update statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, database-performance

Query :

```
update Table 
set ColumUpdate = '{"BCstatus":' + CONVERT(varchar(10), Column2) + ',"Saving":"' + 
 CONVERT(varchar(200), Column3) + '","Successful":' + 
 CONVERT(varchar(10), Column4) + ',"couponCode":"' + Column5 + 
 '","description":"' + Column6 + '","domain":"' + Column7 + '.com","url":"' + Column8+'"}'
```

I have indexes on `Column8` and and another column not present in the query.

The table contains around 1600000 records and its taking lot of time to execute the same.

Comment: If it is static data you can use calculated column. In other case the time is necessary to update the data.

Comment: Maybe the word `static` isn't good choice, I mean, if `ColumnUpdate` column depends on values from other columns and represents some formatted values from them, then you can use calculated column.

Comment: Given the nature of the update, have you considered just using a computed column instead?

Comment: @GordonLinoff did not get you.. Can you plz explain in a bit detail

Comment: @user2129794 . . . You can add a "column" into a table that is really just a calculation on the rows in the table.  That appears to be what this is doing.  You can read about it here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Doing updates/deletes on large number of rows always takes time, more or less regardless of the indeces, because of the way SQL Server manages transactions and the transaction log. To speed thing up, it is always recommended to

a) change recovery model from 'full' to 'bulk logged' and

b) do the update in batches; find a way to divide the update in batches of ~5.000 at the time, this will do wonders.

Ah, and c) disable all indexes on the table while it's running and enable them back when finished.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your update statement is causing multiple page splits. To handle this, you can use fill factor. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459.aspx for futher information. Rebuliding the indexes along with setting fill factor can increase performance  in updates.
You can set fill factor on an existing index using:

```
ALTER INDEX <index name> ON <table name>
REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80);
```